# How to write sql LEAD() and LAG() query in interbase?

Tags: sql, lag, interbase, lead

This query gives the desired results when working with Oracle as my back-end.

```
select field1,
         field2 
from 
   (select field1, 
           field2, 
           LEAD(field2) over (order by r) name 
    from 
       (select rownum r,
              field1,
              field2 
       from t3 
       where field2 = 1
       )
   ) 
where v != nvl(name, -1);
```

But I am facing issues while querying to Interbase database because analytical functions `lag()` and `lead()`are not supported in InterBase6.

My requirement is, if `array field2={1,3,4,4,3,4}`, then I should get results as `{1,3,4,3,4}`.

Comment: Consider switching to Firebird 3, [it supports `lead` and `lag`](http://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html#d0e6678). BTW you are still on Interbase 6? That was released 17 years ago... around the time Firebird 0.x was forked from Interbase 6.

Comment: @Ashish4434 - I see that the question is still opened. If you are satisfied with any of the answer, then `accept` it, so the question could be closed. Read [What to do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  Also try to close your previous questions as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea on `interbase` but I can give you points to write a query to replicate lead function. You can build on that.

1. Find a column you want to order the rows by. The `rownum` you are using in your oracle query is not a correct way to do so. As you cannot guarantee that the results will be displayed in same order all the time. So assuming `field1` is the column you want to order by.
2. Now find a way to generate a sequence number from 1 - `n` in interbase, based on the order above. where `n` being your total number of rows. So your sample table might look like below.

   ```
   +-----+--------+--------+
   | seq | field1 | field2 |
   +-----+--------+--------+
   |   1 |    101 |      1 |
   |   2 |    102 |      3 |
   |   3 |    103 |      4 |
   |   4 |    104 |      4 |
   |   5 |    105 |      3 |
   +-----+--------+--------+
   ```
3. Once you have achieved the above task, you are almost done. You just have to do a self join to replicate lead or lag function. Here is example of `lead`

   ```
   select t1.field1
    ,t1.field2
    ,t2.field1 as lead_field1
    ,t2.field2 as lead_field2
   from table1 t1
   left join
   (select seq-1 as prev_seq,field1,field2
   from table1) t2
   on t1.seq=t2.prev_seq
   ```

The output of this query will be like this, which is what you need to replicate lead function.

```
+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| field1 | field2 | lead_field1 | lead_field2 |
+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
|    101 |      1 | 102         | 3           |
|    102 |      3 | 103         | 4           |
|    103 |      4 | 104         | 4           |
|    104 |      4 | 105         | 3           |
|    105 |      3 | NULL        | NULL        |
+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
```

Sample for the same could be found at

http://rextester.com/IJIU40428